# How to add values in an array in groups of three and return a new array with the sums?

Tags: javascript

im trying to do a convertor that converts values base-16 to base-8 just for fun but i got an issue, the thing is, i need to sum the values of an array in groups of 3, for exemple, an array have `["1","2","0","1"]`, i need to sum the first 3 values and do that for the rest of the array, returning `["3","1"]`, im trying doing without any libraries, i just need to know how can i do this and every try of search about this just find about .push() or .slice()

well, thanks for reading and have a nice day

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by _"sum the values of an array 3 to 3"_ and _"for the position 4 is separate of the first 3"_? Are you trying to sum every 3 values in your array and push those sums into a new array?

Comment: sounds like you are having an interview?

Comment: sorry if you didnt understand, my English is not the best and i have a really big difficulty to explain things

Comment: thats why this is my last resource when i have a question about coding

Comment: and no, Im not in an interview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Array.fn.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) by pushing the element into the result(`a`) if its index(`i`) is divisible by 3, otherwise grab the last element and increase it's value by the current value (`b`).

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 5, 3, 4];

const res = arr.reduce((a, b, i) => {
  if (i % 3 === 0) return [...a, b];
  else { a[a.length - 1] += b; return a; }
}, []);

console.log(arr, res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method to sum the first three elements and the [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method to join the sum result with the rest of the elements of the array in a new array.

For example:

```js
const array = ["0", "1", "2", "1", "3"]
const sum = array.reduce((accumulator, currentValue, index) => {
  return index < 3 ? `${Number(accumulator) + Number(currentValue)}` : accumulator 
})
const result = [sum, ...array.slice(3)] 
console.log(result) // ["3", "1", "3"]
```